# How to disable swagger function of startup class in web api core for integration testing

Tags: integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing integration testing and came across a requirement to disable to calling adding swagger function in startup. I am using the same startup class without customizing it.

Please suggest some solution to get rid of swagger and it's inner function implementation like adding authentication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use a custom startup class for your Integration Testing project. There you can leave out the code to use swagger. 

(or)

2) You can add a key in appsettings.json to identify a test run. 
In Startup.cs - ConfigureServices() and Configure() methods, you can check the key, and if it is test run, you can avoid calling Swagger code.